# Как я могу передвинуть навигационные стрелки в swiper? Я использую React

Tags: reactjs, swiper, carousel

Я хочу передвинуть навигационные стрелки в swiper чуть дальше от рисунков в моем случае div контейнеров. Для этого я импортировал библиотеки Swiper и использую их в React. Для стрелок я использую хук useRef. Я пытался с помощью padding в классе .swipe передвинуть стрелки но не помогло. Так же я пытался с помощью position:absolute с left и right передвинуть в классах swiperNavPrev и swiperNavNext не сработало.

Надеюсь с кодом будет более понятно.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import { Navigation } from "swiper";
import "swiper/css/navigation";

export function Mentors() {
  const swiperNavPrevRef = useRef(null);
  const swiperNavNextRef = useRef(null);


  return (
    <div>
      
       
          <Swiper
            className={styled.swipe}
            modules={[Navigation]}
            spaceBetween={25}
            navigation={{
              prevEl: swiperNavPrevRef.current,
              nextEl: swiperNavNextRef.current,
              prevEl: styled.swiperNavPrev,
              nextEl: styled.swiperNavNext,

            }}
            speed={800}
            slidesPerView={4}
            onInit={(swiper) => {
              swiper.params.navigation.prevEl = swiperNavPrevRef.current;
              swiper.params.navigation.nextEl = swiperNavNextRef.current;
              swiper.navigation.init();
              swiper.navigation.update();
            }}
          >
            <SwiperSlide className={styled.firstSlide}>
              <img src={Blue} className={styled.blue} />

              <div className={styled.mentor}>
                <img src={Aikash} className={styled.image} />
                <h3 className={styled.name}>Айканыш Сыдыкова</h3>
                <p className={styled.deal}>Чем занимается</p>
                <button className={styled.btn}  onClick={() => setOpenModal1(true)} >
                  Узнать больше
                  <span className={styled.forward}>
                    <IoPlayForwardOutline size={20} />
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide className={styled.move}>
              <img src={Red} className={styled.red} />

              <div className={styled.mentor}>
                <img src={Salkyn} className={styled.image} />
                <h3 className={styled.name}>Салкынай Эмилбекова</h3>
                <p className={styled.deal}>Чем занимается</p>

                <button className={styled.btn} onClick={() => setOpenModal2(true)}>
                  Узнать больше
                  <span className={styled.forward}>
                    <IoPlayForwardOutline size={20} />
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <img src={Blue} className={styled.blue} />

              <div className={styled.mentor}>
                <img src={Nurai} className={styled.image} />
                <h3 className={styled.name}>Нурайым Нургазиева</h3>
                <p className={styled.deal}>Чем занимается</p>

                <button className={styled.btn} onClick={() => setOpenModal3(true)}>
                  Узнать больше
                  <span className={styled.forward}>
                    <IoPlayForwardOutline size={20} />
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide className={styled.move}>
              <img src={Red} className={styled.red} />
              <div className={styled.mentor}>
                <img src={Aisezim} className={styled.image} />
                <h3 className={styled.name}>Айсезим Арымбаева</h3>
                <p className={styled.deal}>Чем занимается</p>

                <button className={styled.btn} onClick={() => setOpenModal4(true)}>
                  Узнать больше
                  <span className={styled.forward}>
                    <IoPlayForwardOutline size={20} />
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>

            <SwiperSlide>
              <img src={Blue} className={styled.blue} />

              <div className={styled.mentor}>
                <img src={Aisezim} className={styled.image} />
                <h3 className={styled.name}>Айсезим Арымбаева</h3>
                <p className={styled.deal}>Чем занимается</p>

                <button className={styled.btn}>
                  Узнать больше
                  <span className={styled.forward}>
                    <IoPlayForwardOutline size={20} />
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>

            <SwiperSlide className={styled.move}>
              <img src={Red} className={styled.red} />
              <div className={styled.mentor}>
                <img src={Aisezim} className={styled.image} />
                <h3 className={styled.name}>Айсезим Арымбаева</h3>
                <p className={styled.deal}>Чем занимается</p>

                <button className={styled.btn}>
                  Узнать больше
                  <span className={styled.forward}>
                    <IoPlayForwardOutline size={20} />
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>

            <SwiperSlide>
              <img src={Blue} className={styled.blue} />

              <div className={styled.mentor}>
                <img src={Aisezim} className={styled.image} />
                <h3 className={styled.name}>Айсезим Арымбаева</h3>
                <p className={styled.deal}>Чем занимается</p>

                <button className={styled.btn}>
                  Узнать больше
                  <span className={styled.forward}>
                    <IoPlayForwardOutline size={20} />
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          
            <div className={styled.swiperNavPrev} ref={swiperNavPrevRef}></div>
            <div className={styled.swiperNavNext} ref={swiperNavNextRef}></div>
          </Swiper>
          
       
    </div>
  );
}
```

Для стилей:

```
.swipe {
  height: 600px;
  padding: 70px 20px 0 10px;
}

.firstSlide {
  margin: 0 0 0 1.3em;
}

.swiperNavNext,
.swiperNavPrev {
  top: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

.swiperNavPrev {
  left: -12px;
  background-image: url("./photo/left.svg");
}

.swiperNavNext {
  right: -11px;
  background-image: url("./photo/right.svg");
}

.move {
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У swiper прописано свойство overflow со значением hidden